# Reading an environment variable before it is defined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using an environment variable to be able to read something from a JSON and display in my HTML. My issue is that my HTML is trying to read the environment variable before it has been defined in the .ts and therefore I get an error.

I am currently defining the variable in `ngOnit()` but this gives me an error. I am using `httpclient` to be able to read the JSON (from a server) and obviously what is happening is that the variable is being read in the `HTML` before `httpclient` has got the data.

**HTML**

```
<p>Player One is: {{ id.playerone }} </p>
```

**.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ApComponent implements OnInit {
    id: any = [];

    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpService.get('http://server/info.json').subscribe(
            result => {
            this.id = result;
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Error Occured', error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{  
   "playerone":"ajf806",
   "playertwo":"hof934"
}
```

I get the expected output of `Player One is: ajf806` but I also get an error in the console which is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

It does work and I get the output but I don't want to have the error in the console. Is there a way to delay the HTML reading the environment variable until the JSON has been read?

Comment: are you sure this isn't because you have declared id to be an array, but what you are returning from the server is not an array? The error in question typically occurs when you try to index an empty array...(by empty I mean, uninitialised)

Comment: @StephenByrne When I don't declare it as an array, so `id: any;`. I get this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'playerone' of undefined`.

Comment: The simpliest way is to put a *ngIf="id" on your tag <p> or you can take a look at how prefetching data (route resolver) in Angular works.

You can also use the safe operator as stated by @user2216584.

Comment: @Dritz use just `id;` instead of `id: any = [];`  and also use safe navigation operator  `<p>Player One is: {{ id?.playerone }}`

Comment: why are you even showing values when you didn't get it. You can set *ngIf="id", and when you get your values you will render that p in dom.

Comment: @Dritz - I see. So the array is getting around the first error but masking the real issue that the view is being rendered before the data is loaded. So define the structure up-front e.g.  `var id = null`. And make the display element invisible until id has a value using `*ngIf="id"` as suggested by others. That avoids both of the errors. Long-term though would recommend to use the previously suggested route resolver approach to ensure the data is loaded before the view is rendered, it's more elegant and when you have complex views it works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your variable like this:

```
id: any;
```

also change your template like this:

```
<p>Player One is: {{ id?.playerone }} </p>
```

Another version of the above code [a bit better]:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ApComponent implements OnInit {
    id$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.id$ = this.httpService.get('http://server/info.json')
                       .pipe(
                          catchError((error) => {
                             //handle your error
                             console.log(error);
                          })
                        )
        );
    }
}
```

Now change your template to make use of `async` pipe like this:

```
<ng-conatiner *ngIf="(id$ | async) as id">
 <p>Player One is: {{ id.playerone }} </p>
</ng-container>
```

NOTICE - you are not subscribing to the observable in your component. `async` pipe is taking care of subscription management [i.e. subscribing/unsubscribing.].

Comment: Brilliant! This gets rid of the error. Can you just confirm that is a proper solution and not just a "sketchy" solution to get rid of the error? Thank you

Comment: @Dritz use safe navigation operator as he specified and also use just `id;` instead of `id: any = [];` other way is to load the data using resolve before loading the component but still safe navigation operator  is needed

Comment: @Dritz See my updated answer for a bit better version.